# Specific subclass in python gives syntax error

Tags: python, pygame

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self, name, cost, image):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = cost
        self.image = image

class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, cost, image, damage):
        self.damage = damage
        super().__init__(name, cost, image)

class W_S(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="Wooden Sword", cost = 50, damage = 3, image = pygame.image.load('wood_sword.png')

class S_S(Weapon): #Syntax error here
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="Stone Sword", cost = 75, damage = 6, image = pygame.image.load('stone_sword.png')

class I_S(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="Iron Sword", cost = 100, damage = 9, image = pygame.image.load('iron_sword.png')
```

I am trying to create a basic weapons subclass for S_S(stone sword) and I get an error that highlights the word `class` in `class S_S(Weapon):`.

Comment: If you get a syntax error on a line that seems okay, always check the previous line, particularly for mismatched parentheses or brackets.

Comment: WOOPS! Caught it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing paren at the end of ALL the lines that call `super()`.

Comment: (Except in the `Weapon` class calling the `__init__` method in the `Item` class)